# How to set a cookie in node for a different domain?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, cross-domain, koa

I have a Koa API which is setting a cookie `accessToken` which is used by a react front end, running on a different domain.

Because the cookie is set by the API on a different domain, it is considered a third party cookie by the browser which causes issues. Particularly in Safari where it doesn't get saved in the browser by default.

Is there a way I can tell the server to set a cookie with the domain name of the front end so that the front end thinks it's a first party cookie?

I am setting my cookie like so:

```
ctx.cookies.set("accessToken", accessToken, {
  httpOnly: true,
  domain: "example.com"
})
```

If `example.com` is the front ends domain, should the cookie be interpreted as a first party cookie?

Is this even possible to set a cookie for a different domain?

Thanks

Comment: You could set the cookie directly on the frontend after server response, is the accessToken also in the response from your API?

Comment: I want to avoid setting it in the client side. For security reasons, it is Httponly

Comment: did you get any answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

> The user agent will reject cookies unless the Domain attribute specifies a scope for the cookie that would include the origin server. For example, the user agent will accept a cookie with a Domain attribute of "example.com" or of "foo.example.com" from foo.example.com, but the user agent will not accept a cookie with a Domain attribute of "bar.example.com" or of "baz.foo.example.com".

> NOTE: For security reasons, many user agents are configured to reject Domain attributes that correspond to "public suffixes". For example, some user agents will reject Domain attributes of "com" or "co.uk". (See Section 5.3 for more information.)

But the above mentioned workaround with image/iframe works, though it's not recommended due to its insecurity.

[See RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.3)